# Swift: Imitate iOS Settings screen dimming

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to implement a feature similar to what happens in the iOS Settings screen, whereby the screen background dimming is removed if a search result is found:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s549/sh/01d96373-7ce1-43f5-aed6-a3aea6ce985d/356e9ba510309e1548a4fb384d1bcdcc

I can use `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` when the UISearchController is initialised but is there a way to switch this from true to false as results are fetched and show in the table view?

Thanks